# Oracle SQL '+ 0' syntax for join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I was using Toad's SQL optimizer and it came up with the following addition to my join statements..

instead of say

```
emp.emplid = dept.emplid
```

it suggested

```
emp.emplid = dept.emplid + 0
```

What does the '+ 0' do?  I've searched for the past hour online and I cannot find anything.  I know the (+) meaning, but I've never seen anything like this.

Comment: Just a wild guess... is `emp.emplid` an integer while `dept.emplid` is a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `+ 0` does what it looks like. It adds 0 to `dept.emplid`. But from a performance point of view this does make a difference. By turning that into an expression Oracle is not able to use any index on `dept.emplid`.

So if Oracle is choosing an index on `dept.emplid` but you would rather it used a different index/plan, then adding `+ 0` is a way to influence the optimiser, as there is not longer a match on that particular column. Any expression would have done the trick.

The other way to go about this would be to get into optimiser hints. Although this can be a bit of a pain for big queries.

Comment: I hope you're wrong.  A tool that tries to outsmart the Oracle optimizer, without explaining exactly what it is doing and why, sounds like a waste of time and money.  And plus, Oracle CAN still use indexes in this case.

Comment: Considering the query went from 1 min and 30 seconds to .8 seconds, I'd say it works. There is a comment at the bottom of [this article in the DailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Comments/Surpassing-the-Master.aspx?pg=5) that further details this answer.

Comment: @David: That advice is from the 80s, for the rule based optimizer.  That trick may work for you right now, but it's not very clear, won't work for all versions of Oracle, and doesn't solve the real problem (i.e. why is the optimizer so wrong).

Comment: This optimizer hint indicates a problem with your indexes in the source table. If possible I'd change the indexes before you tune the query!

Answer (score 1):

What the ' + 0' does is to indicate to the optimizer that it should use another index. In other words, I'm pretty sure that one of these two fields (mp.emplid = dept.emplid) has, in addition to the foreign key, also another index specific field. As well, the + 0 cancels the index that takes by default optimizer (the foreign key) and tells it to choose another index.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for the answer! Stack Overflow is an English-language site; I used Google Translate on your answer, but there may be errors. Can you review it for accuracy?