# Why Add Zero in Oracle Query Selection

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on an existing Oracle project and many of the SQL queries are adding zero to some, but not all, of the selected fields:

```
SELECT Value1 + 0 AS Value1, Value2 + 0 AS Value2, Value3, Value4 FROM MYTABLE
```

Is there any reason why 0 is being added to some columns, creating a new column with the same name as the original, and in other cases not. I've found that this technique may sometimes be used in selection criteria to prevent the database from using an index, but these aren't being used as an index.

Comment: Check the datatypes of the source table. It's probably an implicit coersion (hack) from a string to an integer.

Comment: I think it's either implicit coersion like MatBailie said, or it might prevent/bypass the DBMS from caching the results.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: or it's probably to prevent the database from using an index

Comment: speechless (no idea why) https://dbfiddle.uk/42L2B30z

Comment: I don't use Oracle but presumably using "+" forces an implicit cast to a numeric type - if you add `'1'` you'll see it's treated a number for the string also, you don't get concatenation (it would need || or concat)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7072393/266304)? Or possibly related anyway.

Comment: How would this prevent index use? It's in the SELECT clause. There's no predicate anyway.

Comment: @PaulW, That was my question, why would you do this? I did point out that IF it was used in the selection criteria then adding zero would prevent the use of an index. I should also have mentioned that all values have the same numeric definition and are used in the same way by the application.

Answer (score 0):

It is just an (awful imo) way of converting a string to a number

```
SQL> select '123' from dual;

'12
---
123

SQL> select '123'+0 from dual;

   '123'+0
----------
       123
```

I would recommend TO_NUMBER or CAST, both of which can also take additional clauses to handle the situation where 'Value1' might not actually be numeric